# Animate OnTouch event

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview

I'm new inandroid development. I want to animate OnTouch event in my app. Actualy I want a circle that will grow up in the place where I touched a screen. So now I'm using an ImageView with a circle and set it's X and Y. But I see how ImageView move to this point. I'm doing like this:

```
    final ImageView imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgAnimate);
    final Animation animationEnlarge= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation);

    View.OnTouchListener touchListener=new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {

            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                imgView.setX(event.getX());
                imgView.setY(event.getY());
                imgView.startAnimation(animationEnlarge);
            }
        }
    }
```

For ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgAnimate"
    android:src="@drawable/on_touch_circle2"
    android:alpha="80"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
```

And for animation:

```
<scale
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXScale="0.1"
    android:fromYScale="0.1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="100"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5"
    />
```

May be there is some beter ways to do this?

Comment: why not use "event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP" instead? This will start animating only when the touch really is complete

Comment: @Demonick I need animate just AACTION_DOWN